# Notation conflict in calculating expectation of probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $Y$ be a discrete random variable.

Suppose we would like to compute the expectation of its probability function, which is a weird thing to do but it gets my point across. If we just use standard notation, we end up with something like this

$$E_Y[p(Y=Y)] = \sum_y p(Y=y) p(Y=y),$$

where the LHS is somewhat confusing because $Y$ appears twice, and it's hard to interpret. On the other hand, the RHS looks perfectly fine.

Is there a better way of writing/interpreting the LHS? I think the first $Y$ and the second $Y$ might mean different things but I can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: $Y=Y$ with probability $1$ (they are both the same random variable). You can fix this by saying that $Y_1$, $Y_2$ are iid random variables and you want to calculate $\Pr[Y_1 = Y_2]$ (they each have the same distribution as $Y$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem with the notation $P(Y=y)$ is that it's actually only a function of $y$ but its notation has $Y$ in it. If I had explicitly written out the formula for $P(Y=y)$, then there wouldn't be any problem.

Next time, I could probably define $p_Y(y)$ as the probability of $Y$ taking on value $y$. This notation conveniently avoid $p(Y=Y)$.